# Align array with page start

Tags: c, memory-management, offset

I'm developing a program for testing purposes and it's important that I create an array aligned with the page start. That is, `a[0]` is at page offset 0. What would be the way to do it?

Comment: Post the code snippet that you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got using `valloc`, which, according to [this](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_3.html#SEC32), does:

> void *valloc (size_t size)
>
> Allocate a block of size bytes, starting on a page boundary.

Answer (score 1):

`valloc(size)` allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. The memory address will be a multiple of the page size, but it is deprecated. `memalign(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE),size);` is an alternative, but also deprecated.  For future portability use:

```
posix_memalign(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE),size);
```

Comment: The 'standard' function is [`posix_memalign()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_memalign.html). However, the prefix suggests that there were already `memalign()` functions on some platforms, and quite possibly that different platforms had different declarations. Note that `posix_memalign()` is an optional function; it need not be provided by a POSIX implementation.